# ¿Como deshabilitar Ctrl + Flecha hacia abajo en datagridview vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, datagrid

El problema es que en modo de edición al hacer copy-paste se utiliza control y la flecha para moverse a la celda de abajo pero si se mantiene presionado control y la flecha se va hasta el ultimo registro del datagridview y esto hará que los usuarios se equivoquen, si me pueden ayudar de antemano gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo en el evento `KeyDown` del `DataGridView`: si la tecla pulsada es la flecha arriba o abajo y la tecla control está pulsada anulas el evento `KeyPress` para que no ejecute el comportamiento por defecto (ir a la primera o última fila):

```
Private Sub DataGridView_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
    If (e.Control AndAlso (e.KeyCode = Keys.Up OrElse e.KeyCode = Keys.Down)) Then
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Como apuntas en los comentarios esta solución no sirve si el `EditMode` del `DataGridView` está establecido a `EditOnEnter` y te encuentras editando una celda.

Para ese caso la única solución que se me ocurre es la de crear un control personalizado que herede del `DataGridView` y sobrescribir la función `ProcessDataGridViewKey` reemplazando la funcionalidad de `Ctrl + Up` y `Ctrl + Down` por `Up` y `Down`:

```
Public Class CustomDataGridView
    Inherits DataGridView

    <System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission( _
        System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Flags:= _
        System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)> _
    Protected Overrides Function ProcessDataGridViewKey( _
                                                        ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) As Boolean

        If e.Control Then
            If e.KeyCode = Keys.Up Then
                Return ProcessUpKey(Keys.Up)
            ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Down Then
                Return ProcessDownKey(Keys.Down)
            End If
        End If

        Return MyBase.ProcessDataGridViewKey(e)

    End Function

End Class
```

En tu formulario deberías incluir un control `CustomDataGridView` en lugar del `DataGridView`. El nuevo control tendrá la misma funcionalidad excepto el comportamiento de esas dos combinaciones de teclas.

Comment: Que tal, antes que todo gracias, ya probé esa opción, pero solo funciona cuando estoy posicionado sobre una celda que no es editable, si  estoy en una celda que se puede editar y presiono esas teclas, no entra al evento de KeyDown, alguna idea?

Comment: Para editar el valor de las celdas tengo habilitado la opción de `EditMode` en `EditOnEnter` para poder utilizar la opción de `copy-paste` ya que con las otras opciones no deja hacer eso.

Comment: @davidarellano ¿Lo has marcado como respuesta porque ya lo has solucionado o continúas con el problema?

Comment: Lo maraque por que me ayudo, pero aun continuo con el problema, ya que la opcipn que me dio me sirve, pero solo cuando la celda no es editable, si la celda es editable(la mayoria lo son), y preciono las teclas ctrl+flecha asia abajo, no entra el evento `krydown`

Comment: He modificado la respuesta para añadir una posible solución a este caso